# asp:Button causing Server Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, aspx, events

I have a **button** which has probably been implemented wrong, since it causes an **error 500**. The page works fine without the button and I'm not sure where the problem lies.

The .aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<div id="notify_form">
    <p>Please enter a new email:</p>
    <table class="ms-formtable" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" runat="server" id="txtEmail"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-formlabel"></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick='SaveEmail' />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancel" OnClientClick="window.frameElement.cancelPopUp(); return false;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The `SaveEmail` method does nothing at the moment.